# ScheduledExecutorService not working at fixed delay

Tags: android, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using a main activity to call service that collects data from multiple sensors at fixed interval. The issue is that ScheduledExecutorService works for few hours on Nexus 4 and then the delay becomes random, also I tested the app on Moto g, the interval is very sparse from beginning. Any suggestion that what could possibly be wrong? Code is below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intentAccl = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceA.class);
    Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, ServiceA.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),300000, pintent);
}
  public void onDestroy()
  {
      super.onDestroy();
  }



private void launchService(final Intent intent)
{
    ScheduledExecutorService executor=Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          try {
              stopService(intent);
              startService(intent);
              }
          }
     catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occur when trying to run service");
          }
        }
      }
    ,0,10,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: use AlarmManager for that

Comment: You can use TimerTask

Comment: pskink, pls see my updated code, now the problem is that alarm mgr only get called once, is there any thing that i am missing? I am no longer calling launchService

Comment: Did you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: AlarmManager  solved this issue.